# MySQL index size doesn't include all values

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, performance-tuning, size

I have a table with ~1.4M rows and an `id` field as primary key and **not all primary keys are included in index:**

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT(id)) FROM my_table;
+-------------+
| (COUNT(id)) |
+-------------+
|     1391736 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.23 sec)
```

And the index doesn't contain all primary keys

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM my_table;
+-------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+-------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| my_table    |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |     1217360 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+-------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

**As you can see `SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT(` yields 1391736 values, whereas the Index carnality is 1217360**, so about 13% of ids are missing from index.

I had a look at [getting innodb buffer usage](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/215793/getting-innodb-buffer-usage) and it seems InnoDB has free space still:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free';
+-------------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name                 | Value  |
+-------------------------------+--------+
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free | 697127 |
+-------------------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total';
+--------------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name                  | Value  |
+--------------------------------+--------+
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total | 786432 |
+--------------------------------+--------+
```

So I'm confused as to why not all ids are in the index: **Can you point me to some commands I could run to identify where bottleneck is so I can fine-tune configuration to ensure all ids are in the index please?**

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM my_table;` gives accurate value. `SHOW INDEX FROM my_table;` gives approximate value.

Comment: You (the OP) probably meant `select count(distinct id)...`. Also `distinct` is not a function.

Comment: @mustaccio That's true - but in this particular case `id` is PK, so DISTINCT makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Akina for pointing me in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732980/why-cardinality-value-in-mysql-indexes-dont-equal-distinct-count-for-column-val

**Running `ANALYZE TABLE my_table` updated the cardinality to match index size.**

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in `EXPLAIN` and `SHOW INDEX` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS` are approximate.  Live with it.  Even `ANALYZE`, in some situations, will be approximate.

`COUNT(x)` counts how many rows have `x IS NOT NULL`.  *Usually* you want to say `COUNT(*)` to count all rows (after filtering by `WHERE`.  If `id` is "unique", then there will be no difference between `COUNT(id)` and `COUNT(DISTINCT id)`.  If `id` is the PK, then it is also `NOT NULL`, so those will also be the same as `COUNT(*)`.

`Innodb_buffer_pool...` status values will fluctuate.  And there will appear to be some "free" space that never gets used.  Live with it.  It's an optimization.  Don't you buy a new tube of toothpaste *before* you run out?